# Integrate description from one file in another XML file in Perl

Tags: xml, perl

I'm new here so I apologize for my bad english.
I have 2 files (file 1: main-XML-file and file 2: description-file) and I want to integrate the description line per line in a specific position (replace the XX in Hit_def) in the XML-file.

file 1:
Here is the xml-tree:

```
 <BlastOutput>
    <BlastOutput_iterations>
        <Iteration> (gene 1)
            <Iteration_hits>
                <Hit> (1-10)
                    <Hit_def>
        <Iteration> (gene 2)
            <Iteration_hits>
                <Hit> (1-10)
                    <Hit_def>
```

And here the first and last lines, because file is 5 GB big:

```
<?xmlversion="1.0"?>
<BlastOutput>
<BlastOutput_program>RAPSearch</BlastOutput_program>
<BlastOutput_version>RAPSearch2</BlastOutput_version>
<BlastOutput_reference>YonganZhao,HaixuTangandYuzhenYe.RAPSearch2:afastandmemory-efficientproteinsimilaritysearchtoolfornextgenerationsequencingdata.Bioinformatics2012,28(1):125-126</BlastOutput_reference>
<BlastOutput_db>/mreferate/dwolff/RAPSearch2.23/db/NCBI_nr_dec15</BlastOutput_db>
<BlastOutput_param>
<Parameters>
</Parameters>
</BlastOutput_param>
<BlastOutput_iterations>
<Iteration>
<Iteration_iter-num>1</Iteration_iter-num>
<Iteration_query-def>gene_id_1</Iteration_query-def>
<Iteration_query-len>37</Iteration_query-len>
<Iteration_hits>
<Hit>
<Hit_num>1</Hit_num>
<Hit_id>gi|939543432|gb|KPV42113.1|</Hit_id>
<Hit_def>XX</Hit_def>
<Hit_accession>KPV42113.1</Hit_accession>
<Hit_len>162</Hit_len>
<Hit_hsps>
<Hsp>
<Hsp_num>1</Hsp_num>
<Hsp_bit-score>58.151</Hsp_bit-score>
<Hsp_score>139</Hsp_score>
<Hsp_evalue>-5.6061</Hsp_evalue>
<Hsp_query-from>1</Hsp_query-from>
<Hsp_query-to>37</Hsp_query-to>
<Hsp_hit-from>54</Hsp_hit-from>
<Hsp_hit-to>90</Hsp_hit-to>
<Hsp_query-frame>0</Hsp_query-frame>
<Hsp_identity>28</Hsp_identity>
<Hsp_positive>33</Hsp_positive>
<Hsp_align-len>37</Hsp_align-len>
<Hsp_qseq>MVVCDEPVSALDVSVQAAVLTLLVEIQQQHETAMILI</Hsp_qseq>
<Hsp_hseq>LVLCDEPVSALDVSVQAAVLNLLLEIQREHGTTMIFI</Hsp_hseq>
<Hsp_midline>+V+CDEPVSALDVSVQAAVLLL+EIQ++HTMII</Hsp_midline>
</Hsp>
</Hit_hsps>
</Hit>
<Hit>
<Hit_num>2</Hit_num>
<Hit_id>gi|385280362|gb|EIF44286.1|</Hit_id>
<Hit_def>XX</Hit_def>
<Hit_accession>EIF44286.1</Hit_accession>
<Hit_len>327</Hit_len>
<Hit_hsps>
<Hsp>
<Hsp_num>1</Hsp_num>
<Hsp_bit-score>54.6842</Hsp_bit-score>
<Hsp_score>130</Hsp_score>
<Hsp_evalue>-4.56249</Hsp_evalue>
<Hsp_query-from>1</Hsp_query-from>
<Hsp_query-to>37</Hsp_query-to>
<Hsp_hit-from>169</Hsp_hit-from>
<Hsp_hit-to>205</Hsp_hit-to>
<Hsp_query-frame>0</Hsp_query-frame>
<Hsp_identity>24</Hsp_identity>
<Hsp_positive>31</Hsp_positive>
<Hsp_align-len>37</Hsp_align-len>
<Hsp_qseq>MVVCDEPVSALDVSVQAAVLTLLVEIQQQHETAMILI</Hsp_qseq>
<Hsp_hseq>LVICDEPVSALDVSVQAQIINLLQELQTEHNTAMLFI</Hsp_hseq>
<Hsp_midline>+V+CDEPVSALDVSVQA++LLE+Q+HTAM+I</Hsp_midline>
</Hsp>
</Hit_hsps>
</Hit>
<Hit>
<Hit_num>3</Hit_num>
<Hit_id>gi|550913550|ref|WP_022666548.1|</Hit_id>
<Hit_def>XX</Hit_def>
<Hit_accession>WP_022666548.1</Hit_accession>
<Hit_len>721</Hit_len>
<Hit_hsps>
<Hsp>
<Hsp_num>1</Hsp_num>
<Hsp_bit-score>53.5286</Hsp_bit-score>
<Hsp_score>127</Hsp_score>
<Hsp_evalue>-4.21462</Hsp_evalue>
<Hsp_query-from>1</Hsp_query-from>
<Hsp_query-to>37</Hsp_query-to>
<Hsp_hit-from>549</Hsp_hit-from>
<Hsp_hit-to>585</Hsp_hit-to>
<Hsp_query-frame>0</Hsp_query-frame>
<Hsp_identity>27</Hsp_identity>
<Hsp_positive>31</Hsp_positive>
<Hsp_align-len>37</Hsp_align-len>
<Hsp_qseq>MVVCDEPVSALDVSVQAAVLTLLVEIQQQHETAMILI</Hsp_qseq>
<Hsp_hseq>MVICDEPVSALDVSVQAAVLNLLNEIKEEMGTTMIFI</Hsp_hseq>
<Hsp_midline>MV+CDEPVSALDVSVQAAVLLLEI+++TMII</Hsp_midline>
</Hsp>
</Hit_hsps>
</Hit>
...
</Iteration_hits>
<Iteration_stat>
<Statistics>
<Statistics_db-num>77704984</Statistics_db-num>
<Statistics_db-len>28292933896</Statistics_db-len>
<Statistics_hsp-len>0</Statistics_hsp-len>
<Statistics_eff-space>0</Statistics_eff-space>
<Statistics_kappa>0.041</Statistics_kappa>
<Statistics_lambda>0.267</Statistics_lambda>
<Statistics_entropy>0.14</Statistics_entropy>
</Statistics>
</Iteration_stat>
</Iteration>
</BlastOutput_iterations>
</BlastOutput>
```

file 2:

```
peptide ABC transporter ATPase, partial [Kouleothrix aurantiaca]
oligopeptide ABC transporter [gamma proteobacterium BDW918]
ABC transporter ATP-binding protein [Desulfospira joergensenii]
```

output should be:

```
<?xmlversion="1.0"?>
<BlastOutput>
<BlastOutput_program>RAPSearch</BlastOutput_program>
<BlastOutput_version>RAPSearch2</BlastOutput_version>
<BlastOutput_reference>YonganZhao,HaixuTangandYuzhenYe.RAPSearch2:afastandmemory-efficientproteinsimilaritysearchtoolfornextgenerationsequencingdata.Bioinformatics2012,28(1):125-126</BlastOutput_reference>
<BlastOutput_db>/mreferate/dwolff/RAPSearch2.23/db/NCBI_nr_dec15</BlastOutput_db>
<BlastOutput_param>
<Parameters>
</Parameters>
</BlastOutput_param>
<BlastOutput_iterations>
<Iteration>
<Iteration_iter-num>1</Iteration_iter-num>
<Iteration_query-def>gene_id_1</Iteration_query-def>
<Iteration_query-len>37</Iteration_query-len>
<Iteration_hits>
<Hit>
<Hit_num>1</Hit_num>
<Hit_id>gi|939543432|gb|KPV42113.1|</Hit_id>
<Hit_def>peptide ABC transporter ATPase, partial [Kouleothrix aurantiaca]</Hit_def>
<Hit_accession>KPV42113.1</Hit_accession>
<Hit_len>162</Hit_len>
<Hit_hsps>
<Hsp>
<Hsp_num>1</Hsp_num>
<Hsp_bit-score>58.151</Hsp_bit-score>
<Hsp_score>139</Hsp_score>
<Hsp_evalue>-5.6061</Hsp_evalue>
<Hsp_query-from>1</Hsp_query-from>
<Hsp_query-to>37</Hsp_query-to>
<Hsp_hit-from>54</Hsp_hit-from>
<Hsp_hit-to>90</Hsp_hit-to>
<Hsp_query-frame>0</Hsp_query-frame>
<Hsp_identity>28</Hsp_identity>
<Hsp_positive>33</Hsp_positive>
<Hsp_align-len>37</Hsp_align-len>
<Hsp_qseq>MVVCDEPVSALDVSVQAAVLTLLVEIQQQHETAMILI</Hsp_qseq>
<Hsp_hseq>LVLCDEPVSALDVSVQAAVLNLLLEIQREHGTTMIFI</Hsp_hseq>
<Hsp_midline>+V+CDEPVSALDVSVQAAVLLL+EIQ++HTMII</Hsp_midline>
</Hsp>
</Hit_hsps>
</Hit>
<Hit>
<Hit_num>2</Hit_num>
<Hit_id>gi|385280362|gb|EIF44286.1|</Hit_id>
<Hit_def>oligopeptide ABC transporter [gamma proteobacterium BDW918]</Hit_def>
<Hit_accession>EIF44286.1</Hit_accession>
<Hit_len>327</Hit_len>
<Hit_hsps>
<Hsp>
<Hsp_num>1</Hsp_num>
<Hsp_bit-score>54.6842</Hsp_bit-score>
<Hsp_score>130</Hsp_score>
<Hsp_evalue>-4.56249</Hsp_evalue>
<Hsp_query-from>1</Hsp_query-from>
<Hsp_query-to>37</Hsp_query-to>
<Hsp_hit-from>169</Hsp_hit-from>
<Hsp_hit-to>205</Hsp_hit-to>
<Hsp_query-frame>0</Hsp_query-frame>
<Hsp_identity>24</Hsp_identity>
<Hsp_positive>31</Hsp_positive>
<Hsp_align-len>37</Hsp_align-len>
<Hsp_qseq>MVVCDEPVSALDVSVQAAVLTLLVEIQQQHETAMILI</Hsp_qseq>
<Hsp_hseq>LVICDEPVSALDVSVQAQIINLLQELQTEHNTAMLFI</Hsp_hseq>
<Hsp_midline>+V+CDEPVSALDVSVQA++LLE+Q+HTAM+I</Hsp_midline>
</Hsp>
</Hit_hsps>
</Hit>
<Hit>
<Hit_num>3</Hit_num>
<Hit_id>gi|550913550|ref|WP_022666548.1|</Hit_id>
<Hit_def>ABC transporter ATP-binding protein [Desulfospira joergensenii]</Hit_def>
<Hit_accession>WP_022666548.1</Hit_accession>
<Hit_len>721</Hit_len>
<Hit_hsps>
<Hsp>
<Hsp_num>1</Hsp_num>
<Hsp_bit-score>53.5286</Hsp_bit-score>
<Hsp_score>127</Hsp_score>
<Hsp_evalue>-4.21462</Hsp_evalue>
<Hsp_query-from>1</Hsp_query-from>
<Hsp_query-to>37</Hsp_query-to>
<Hsp_hit-from>549</Hsp_hit-from>
<Hsp_hit-to>585</Hsp_hit-to>
<Hsp_query-frame>0</Hsp_query-frame>
<Hsp_identity>27</Hsp_identity>
<Hsp_positive>31</Hsp_positive>
<Hsp_align-len>37</Hsp_align-len>
<Hsp_qseq>MVVCDEPVSALDVSVQAAVLTLLVEIQQQHETAMILI</Hsp_qseq>
<Hsp_hseq>MVICDEPVSALDVSVQAAVLNLLNEIKEEMGTTMIFI</Hsp_hseq>
<Hsp_midline>MV+CDEPVSALDVSVQAAVLLLEI+++TMII</Hsp_midline>
</Hsp>
</Hit_hsps>
</Hit>
...
</Iteration_hits>
<Iteration_stat>
<Statistics>
<Statistics_db-num>77704984</Statistics_db-num>
<Statistics_db-len>28292933896</Statistics_db-len>
<Statistics_hsp-len>0</Statistics_hsp-len>
<Statistics_eff-space>0</Statistics_eff-space>
<Statistics_kappa>0.041</Statistics_kappa>
<Statistics_lambda>0.267</Statistics_lambda>
<Statistics_entropy>0.14</Statistics_entropy>
</Statistics>
</Iteration_stat>
</Iteration>
</BlastOutput_iterations>
</BlastOutput>
```

First trials to write a script gave no results and were disastrous. So I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and to the perl tag. Please [edit] your question to include those first trials. We will not write code for you, but instead help you fix yours. It also helps to include _valid_ XML. The stuff you show is not. The `<Hit>` and `<Hsp>` tags never closed. Please include code and input either exactly the way it is, or simplified in a way that it still reproduces the problem. See [mcve], and also read [ask]. :)

Comment: Thank you for adding more information and making the XML valid. But please also add the code that you tried with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just updated the script to match the new XML structure for your new XML above.

Check my comments in the code below:

```
    use strict;                                                                                                                                                                                      
    use warnings;
    use XML::Simple;

    #First, parse your XML into a hash
    open my $MF1,'<', 'my_xml.xml';
    my $xml = XMLin($MF1);
    close $MF1;

    =com    This the $xml sample
    $VAR1 = {
        'BlastOutput_db' => '/mreferate/dwolff/RAPSearch2.23/db/NCBI_nr_dec15',
        'BlastOutput_program' => 'RAPSearch',
        'BlastOutput_param' => {
        'Parameters' => {}
        },
        'BlastOutput_reference' => 'YonganZhao,HaixuTangandYuzhenYe.RAPSearch2:afastandmemory-efficientproteinsimilaritysearchtoolfornextgenerationsequencingdata.Bioinformatics2012,28(1):125-126',
        'BlastOutput_version' => 'RAPSearch2',
        'BlastOutput_iterations' => {
            'Iteration' => {
                'Iteration_hits' => {
                    'Hit' => [
                        {
                        'Hit_accession' => 'KPV42113.1',
                        'Hit_id' => 'gi|939543432|gb|KPV42113.1|',
                        'Hit_hsps' => {
                        'Hsp' => {
                        'Hsp_hseq' => 'LVLCDEPVSALDVSVQAAVLNLLLEIQREHGTTMIFI',
                        'Hsp_bit-score' => '58.151',
                        'Hsp_identity' => '28',
                        'Hsp_align-len' => '37',
                        'Hsp_query-frame' => '0',
                        'Hsp_query-from' => '1',
                        'Hsp_qseq' => 'MVVCDEPVSALDVSVQAAVLTLLVEIQQQHETAMILI',
                        'Hsp_evalue' => '-5.6061',
                        'Hsp_midline' => '+V+CDEPVSALDVSVQAAVLLL+EIQ++HTMII',
                        'Hsp_num' => '1',
                        'Hsp_positive' => '33',
                        'Hsp_hit-from' => '54',
                        'Hsp_score' => '139',
                        'Hsp_hit-to' => '90',
                        'Hsp_query-to' => '37'
                        }
                        },
                    'Hit_len' => '162',
                    'Hit_num' => '1',
                    'Hit_def' => 'XX'
                    },
                    {
                    'Hit_accession' => 'EIF44286.1',
                    'Hit_id' => 'gi|385280362|gb|EIF44286.1|',
                    'Hit_hsps' => {
                    'Hsp' => {
                    'Hsp_hit-from' => '169',
                    'Hsp_positive' => '31',
                    'Hsp_score' => '130',
                    'Hsp_query-to' => '37',
                    'Hsp_hit-to' => '205',
                    'Hsp_num' => '1',
                    'Hsp_midline' => '+V+CDEPVSALDVSVQA++LLE+Q+HTAM+I',
                    'Hsp_align-len' => '37',
                    'Hsp_query-frame' => '0',
                    'Hsp_qseq' => 'MVVCDEPVSALDVSVQAAVLTLLVEIQQQHETAMILI',
                    'Hsp_evalue' => '-4.56249',
                    'Hsp_query-from' => '1',
                    'Hsp_bit-score' => '54.6842',
                    'Hsp_identity' => '24',
                    'Hsp_hseq' => 'LVICDEPVSALDVSVQAQIINLLQELQTEHNTAMLFI'
                    }
                    },
                    'Hit_def' => 'XX',
                    'Hit_len' => '327',
                    'Hit_num' => '2'
                    },

=cut

# Save the second file into an array
open my $MF2, '<', 'file2';
chomp( my @defs = <$MF2> );
close $MF2;

# Update the XML hash
foreach my $iteration ( @{ $xml->{'BlastOutput_iterations'}{'Iteration'}}){ 
foreach my $hit ( @{$iteration->{'Iteration_hits'}{'Hit'}}){    
$hit->{'Hit_def'} = @defs[ $hit->{'Hit_num'} - 1 ];
}}

# Write the new XML to file1
open my $MF1_new, '>', 'my_xml.xml';
XMLout($xml, OutputFile => $MF1_new, NoAttr => 1, RootName => 'BlastOutput' );
close $MF1_new;
```

Comment: This is not a good answer. You should explain what you are doing, and why. Code-only answers are discouraged. Furthermore, you are using neither `use strict` nor `use warnings`, and [the docs of XML::Simple discourage its use](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple#STATUS-OF-THIS-MODULE) because it is horrible to maintain code that uses it. Please revise your answer.

Comment: You're right regarding the `use strict` and `use warnings`. But for the explaining my code I already added some main comments in the code showing the steps, isn't that enough?

Comment: Well, it's enough to solve the problem, but not to understand what's going on. I consider a good answer to have a bit more explanation, and some reasoning as to why you would use XML::Simple specifically. And since OP says the file is 5 GB of size, it's probably going to eat **a lot of memory**. Explain how that would not be a problem in your solution. Simply throwing code at someone is not what Stack Overflow is about. But that's just my five cents. ;)

Comment: Thanks for shedding the light on the performance point, I'm not that senior in Perl, but after some research I found that by installing `XML::SAX::Expat` or `XML::SAX::ExpatXS` parsers, `XML::Simple` performance should be much better compared to using the default, old, `XML::SAX` parser - http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Simple/lib/XML/Simple/FAQ.pod#Why_is_XML::Simple_so_slow?

 What do you think?

Comment: Hi. First thanks for the quick answer. I've tried this script with a reduced xml-file and I got an error: Not a HASH reference at xml2xml.pl line 21. This is the line with the foreach loop. Have you any idea what is wrong?

Comment: The XML should be of exactly the same structure as the one you supplied in your question above, if you try the script with the same XML portion above it'll run as expected. In case you are using another XML you need to state that new one so that we edit the script to fit with your new XML.

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad explanation; the "reduced xml-file" has the same XML portion as I showed in my qestion, only the number of entries is less. Nevertheless the script don't run and has the error I posted in the last commend. Have you tried the script at your computer?

Comment: Yes of course I tried it on the same XML in your question and it's working fine for me. Would you please check if your xml file gas the <?xmlversion="1.0"?> line, and if so please try removing it, save the change, and then rerun the script. Let me know if this works or not.

Comment: I just tried the xml with the <?xmlversion="1.0"?> tag and it failed, and I found that that tag should be either removed or replaced by this one `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: Also you need to make sure that the xml file is in the same directory as the script, they both should be on the same level, otherwise you need to modify the files paths in the script to point to the correct files.

Comment: I posted my output to an answer, because the script is to long for a comment. I had to delete the first line and yes the files and the script are in the same directory. So thank you for your help and your patience with me. Now I have to try the script with the big 5GB file. I hope it works also.

Comment: I've tried to transfer the script to the real xml-file and have realized the major xml-tree, so that your script didn't work anymore. I've updated my question with the tree so I hope my problem get clear.

Comment: Man, once you parse the XML into the $xml, you can access all its elements since whatever the structure is, since $xml is ref to a hash now. So whatever the XML tree is, you just have to modify the way you're updating the element, so in this case it seems like you'll have an array of `Iteration`, and inside each one you have another array of `hit`, so replace the foreach loop by two loops, one looping over each iteration of the iterants array, and an inner loop looping over each hit of the current iteration. Please try modifying the script as such, and let me know the latest

Comment: Try using `print Data::Dumper::Dumper($xml)` to see the exact structure of the $xml so that you can easily locate the iterations array and the hits array

Comment: Thanks for your help. I updated the script and it worked so far with one exception: The script replace the first 10 descriptions and then it started to replace again the first 10 descriptions and not go through the description list. Can you fix this problem?

Comment: I added the @{} to the inner foreach. This should be working now I guess

Comment: Unfortunately it don't worked. For every 'Iteration' the script replaced the same first 10 descriptions. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've got it. Only the output is a little bit displaced:

```
<BlastOutput>
  <BlastOutput_db>/mreferate/dwolff/RAPSearch2.23/db/NCBI_nr_dec15</BlastOutput_db>
  <BlastOutput_iterations>
    <name>Iteration</name>
    <Iteration_hits>
      <Hit>
        <Hit_accession>KPV42113.1</Hit_accession>
        <Hit_def>peptide ABC transporter ATPase, partial [Kouleothrix aurantiaca]
</Hit_def>
        <Hit_hsps>
          <name>Hsp</name>
          <Hsp_align-len>37</Hsp_align-len>
          <Hsp_bit-score>58.151</Hsp_bit-score>
          <Hsp_evalue>-5.6061</Hsp_evalue>
          <Hsp_hit-from>54</Hsp_hit-from>
          <Hsp_hit-to>90</Hsp_hit-to>
          <Hsp_hseq>LVLCDEPVSALDVSVQAAVLNLLLEIQREHGTTMIFI</Hsp_hseq>
          <Hsp_identity>28</Hsp_identity>
          <Hsp_midline>+V+CDEPVSALDVSVQAAVLLL+EIQ++HTMII</Hsp_midline>
          <Hsp_num>1</Hsp_num>
          <Hsp_positive>33</Hsp_positive>
          <Hsp_qseq>MVVCDEPVSALDVSVQAAVLTLLVEIQQQHETAMILI</Hsp_qseq>
          <Hsp_query-frame>0</Hsp_query-frame>
          <Hsp_query-from>1</Hsp_query-from>
          <Hsp_query-to>37</Hsp_query-to>
          <Hsp_score>139</Hsp_score>
        </Hit_hsps>
        <Hit_id>gi|939543432|gb|KPV42113.1|</Hit_id>
        <Hit_len>162</Hit_len>
        <Hit_num>1</Hit_num>
      </Hit>
      <Hit>
        <Hit_accession>EIF44286.1</Hit_accession>
        <Hit_def>oligopeptide ABC transporter [gamma proteobacterium BDW918]
</Hit_def>
        <Hit_hsps>
          <name>Hsp</name>
          <Hsp_align-len>37</Hsp_align-len>
          <Hsp_bit-score>54.6842</Hsp_bit-score>
          <Hsp_evalue>-4.56249</Hsp_evalue>
          <Hsp_hit-from>169</Hsp_hit-from>
          <Hsp_hit-to>205</Hsp_hit-to>
          <Hsp_hseq>LVICDEPVSALDVSVQAQIINLLQELQTEHNTAMLFI</Hsp_hseq>
          <Hsp_identity>24</Hsp_identity>
          <Hsp_midline>+V+CDEPVSALDVSVQA++LLE+Q+HTAM+I</Hsp_midline>
          <Hsp_num>1</Hsp_num>
          <Hsp_positive>31</Hsp_positive>
          <Hsp_qseq>MVVCDEPVSALDVSVQAAVLTLLVEIQQQHETAMILI</Hsp_qseq>
          <Hsp_query-frame>0</Hsp_query-frame>
          <Hsp_query-from>1</Hsp_query-from>
          <Hsp_query-to>37</Hsp_query-to>
          <Hsp_score>130</Hsp_score>
        </Hit_hsps>
        <Hit_id>gi|385280362|gb|EIF44286.1|</Hit_id>
        <Hit_len>327</Hit_len>
        <Hit_num>2</Hit_num>
      </Hit>
      <Hit>
        <Hit_accession>WP_022666548.1</Hit_accession>
        <Hit_def>ABC transporter ATP-binding protein [Desulfospira joergensenii]
</Hit_def>
        <Hit_hsps>
          <name>Hsp</name>
          <Hsp_align-len>37</Hsp_align-len>
          <Hsp_bit-score>53.5286</Hsp_bit-score>
          <Hsp_evalue>-4.21462</Hsp_evalue>
          <Hsp_hit-from>549</Hsp_hit-from>
          <Hsp_hit-to>585</Hsp_hit-to>
          <Hsp_hseq>MVICDEPVSALDVSVQAAVLNLLNEIKEEMGTTMIFI</Hsp_hseq>
          <Hsp_identity>27</Hsp_identity>
          <Hsp_midline>MV+CDEPVSALDVSVQAAVLLLEI+++TMII</Hsp_midline>
          <Hsp_num>1</Hsp_num>
          <Hsp_positive>31</Hsp_positive>
          <Hsp_qseq>MVVCDEPVSALDVSVQAAVLTLLVEIQQQHETAMILI</Hsp_qseq>
          <Hsp_query-frame>0</Hsp_query-frame>
          <Hsp_query-from>1</Hsp_query-from>
          <Hsp_query-to>37</Hsp_query-to>
          <Hsp_score>127</Hsp_score>
        </Hit_hsps>
        <Hit_id>gi|550913550|ref|WP_022666548.1|</Hit_id>
        <Hit_len>721</Hit_len>
        <Hit_num>3</Hit_num>
      </Hit>
    </Iteration_hits>
    <Iteration_iter-num>1</Iteration_iter-num>
    <Iteration_query-def>gene_id_1</Iteration_query-def>
    <Iteration_query-len>37</Iteration_query-len>
    <Iteration_stat>
      <name>Statistics</name>
      <Statistics_db-len>28292933896</Statistics_db-len>
      <Statistics_db-num>77704984</Statistics_db-num>
      <Statistics_eff-space>0</Statistics_eff-space>
      <Statistics_entropy>0.14</Statistics_entropy>
      <Statistics_hsp-len>0</Statistics_hsp-len>
      <Statistics_kappa>0.041</Statistics_kappa>
      <Statistics_lambda>0.267</Statistics_lambda>
    </Iteration_stat>
  </BlastOutput_iterations>
  <BlastOutput_param>
    <name>Parameters</name>
  </BlastOutput_param>
  <BlastOutput_program>RAPSearch</BlastOutput_program>
  <BlastOutput_reference>YonganZhao,HaixuTangandYuzhenYe.RAPSearch2:afastandmemory-efficientproteinsimilaritysearchtoolfornextgenerationsequencingdata.Bioinformatics2012,28(1):125-126</BlastOutput_reference>
  <BlastOutput_version>RAPSearch2</BlastOutput_version>
</BlastOutput>
```